# Sitecore Sxa Checklist Filter Multiple selection not showing result

Tags: sxa, solr, search-facet, sxa-search

I have a multilist field **Services** in sitecore which I have added in solr index as stringCollection using the below configuration.

```
<field fieldName="servicetitles" returnType="stringCollection" type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.ComputedFields.ResolvedLinks,  Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search" referenceField="services" contentField="title"/>
```

I have a Services facet using the **servicetitles** field and referring it in dropdown filter. I have enabled multiple selection in the Services dropdown filter, but when selecting more than one service, the search results are not shown even if there are providers who offer both the services selected.

This multilist selection does not work in dropdown checklist filter also.

Regards.
Christo

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @GauravAgarwal yes it is fixed by the sitecore provided hotfix SC Hotfix 463229-1 SXA 9.3.0.2589. Seems it should be installed on particular sitecore version only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed by the sitecore provided hotfix SC Hotfix 463229-1 SXA 9.3.0.2589. Seems it should be installed on particular sitecore version only.